# hql - how to select conditional query in hibernate

Tags: java, database, hibernate, list

i have data student at database.
and have field called 'name', how to conditional query ignore case?
i have data id=1,name=john 
i will get data from query in hibernate if i query ignore case name field, this is my code:

```
List list = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession()
                .createQuery("from Student where name = :param")
                .setParameter("param", value)
                .list();
```

if iam typing John or JOHN or jOhn or JOHn or etc i will get data from my database.
how to solve it?

Comment: Is the provided answer what you where looking for? if yes, please mark the answer as the right solution. if not i can provide you a `ilike` solution.

Answer (score 0):

Use lower case in both sides:

```
List list = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession()
                .createQuery("from Student where lower(name) = :param")
                .setParameter("param", value.toLowerCase())
                .list();
```